# How many users can I create on a SQL Azure Server?

Tags: azure-sql-database

I was looking at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-manage-logins/ searching for some documentation about limits and/or restrictions of the amount of the users I can create on SQL Azure Server, but I didn't get anyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no specific limit on number of users. A SQL database can handle 2^31 objects which includes tables, views, sprocs, etc... and users so you can create LOTS of users (doesn't mean you should).

The article you referenced points out the maximum **concurrent** logins of 30. That means only 30 unique logins are permitted at any time. For most environments, this translates to 30 **concurrent** users. That means you can create 1000 user accounts in your database but only 30 can actively access the database at any given time.

Comment: Thanks, this is the kind of answer I was looking for. To keep in record, I'll try to resell SQL Azure Database as a Service, but I had this concern.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be happy to help.  Can you please be a little more specific about what limits you think you might hit?  There are no limits on users for security in SQL DB.

Guy

Comment: I found this one https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-service-tiers/, but it says that I can have 30 concurrent logins on the basic tier, but it doesn't says that I have a limit of 30 logins.

Comment: You can create as many as needed, however at any point you can only have 30 connections (whatever based on the DTU) to the database